# blank input submit blank li in ul by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Each time I am input a new value in input and when I submit it. It's adding in ul and the input getting blank but when I click the blank input it also adding blank li in ul how can I solve it.

this the is the code

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="addList">
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Add">
</form>

<ul id="listItem"></ul>
```

jquery

```
    $(function (){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var $item = $('#addList').val();
        $('ul#listItem').append('<li>'+ $item + '</li>');
        $item = $('#addList').val(' ');
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the code? See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your link doesn't work.

Comment: You need to update you fiddle link.

Comment: And clarify your question. It doesn't make much sense.

Comment: "this the jsfiddle link" - Nope. Thats a link to the image.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see your code but I guess you just don't want any undefined value to be submitted.

Just check for null inputs;

```
if ($("#yourinput").val != "") myFunc(somevar);
```

Please provide your code instead of an image if you are asking for proper answers.

Answer (score 0):

add `not empty condition`  `if($item !='')`

```js
$(function (){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var $item = $('#addList').val();
        if($item.trim() !='')
        {
        $('ul#listItem').append('<li>'+ $item + '</li>');
        $item = $('#addList').val(' ');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="addList">
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Add">
</form>

<ul id="listItem"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#addbtn").on("click",function(){
val = $("#lival").val();
if(val.trim() == ''){
 alert("Please enter valid input!")
}else{
html= "<li>"+val+"</li>";
 $("#ulid").append(html);
 $("#lival").val('') ;
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="lival"><button id="addbtn">Add</button>

<ul id="ulid">
  
</ul>
```

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nbd5jjdx/